# Select statement echoing out rows twice

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables on my database. Table `tableA` looks like this:

```
 taid | tanum | tarelation
---------------------------
  30  |  22   |  101
  31  |  88   |  101
```

And table `tableB` looks like this:

```
 tbid | tbnum | tbrelation
---------------------------
  1   |  10   |  101
  2   |  20   |  101
```

I want to echo out all rows for `tanum` and `tbnum` - should be only 4 results echoed out, but instead my code is *doubling* each result echoed, so it is displaying 8 results total (should not do that). This is the unwanted result I am getting:

```
22
10
88
10
22
20
88
20
```

Why is it doing that? The result should not look like that, but like this:

```
22
88
10
20
```

Please help me fix this. This is my code:

```
<?php
$columns = [];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
  SELECT tableA.*, tableB.*
  FROM tableA
  INNER JOIN tableB
  ON tableA.tarelation = tableB.tbrelation");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
  $columns[] = $row;
}
$stmt->close();
?>
<div>
<?php foreach($columns as $column): ?>
    <div><?php echo $column->tanum; ?></div>
    <div><?php echo $column->tbnum; ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: 2 X 2 = 4.  Both rows in each table join to both rows in the other table.

Comment: @Andrew So what would you suggest I do?

Comment: Why do a JOIN at all? From your description it seems you don't care if the item is a tanum or a tbnum, you just want one combined list. In that case UNION would be more appropriate. `SELECT tanum FROM TableA UNION SELECT tbnum FROM TableB`

Comment: Sounds like you should not have two tables to begin with, but one with an additional column that decides whether the record belongs to a or b (whatever those actually are.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) concept. For that, you can use UNION or UNION ALL keyword.

Note:

- While using ***UNION***, duplicate records will be removed, so if you want to keep all records use UNION ALL.
- You don't need to create sub-queries for that.

```
SELECT taid AS ID, tanum AS NUM, tarelation AS RELATION FROM tableA 
UNION ALL
SELECT tbid AS ID, tbnum AS NUM, tbrelation AS RELATION FROM tableB;
```

Comment: A far more cleaner and simpler solution, did not know about the UNION ALL keyword either. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL query does not produce a list of just the `tanum` and `tbnum` values that you show as your output.  If you want a list of just the `tanum` and `tbnum` values in all tables (as you show as your desired result), this will do it:

```
select tanum from TableA
union
select tbnum from TableB;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it seems like you just want to append both these tables:

```
select a.*
from
(select taid as ID,tanum as NUM,tarelation as RELATION from tableA
UNION
select tbid as ID,tbnum as NUM,tbrelation as RELATION from tableB)a
```

Comment: Ah I see now. So I'm supposed to do a union and not a join. Thankfully this also demonstrates how to select all rows. Guess I was using the wrong thing, thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

SQL query is fine.

[image: SQL query from the question]

I believe the following result looks like something expected by you:

[image: SQL query result]

But you are just printing values twice by yourself:

```
<div><?php echo $column->tanum; ?></div>
<div><?php echo $column->tbnum; ?></div>
```

> Row 1, "tanum": 22
>
> Row 1, "tbnum": 10
>
> Row 2, "tanum": 88
>
> Row 2, "tbnum": 10
>
> Row 3, "tanum": 22
>
> Row 3, "tbnum": 20
>
> Row 4, "tanum": 88
>
> Row 5, "tbnum": 20

Answer (score -2):

It's the SQL

The inner join doesn't ensure that only 1 rows in both table will be connected

Comment: So how would I fix this?

Comment: This seems more appropriate as a comment rather a solution.

Comment: @misner3456 By making sure that each value in `tarelation` and `tbrelation` only exists once. Since each value exists twice, it connects both rows in tableB to each row from tableA. Dumping the `$columns` with `print_r` or something similar will show that there's 4 items in the array, from which you echo 2 items for each item, resulting in 8 printed items. You could enforce this uniqueness with setting the `tarelation` and `tbrelation` `UNIQUE`, maybe even setting up a foreign key constraint or using a 3rd table that connects the two.

Comment: @Hunman I think I see what you mean now. Thank you for taking the time to explain this, really helped.